# И еще запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Из текста по соционике: "В понимании Достоевского(,) акт утешения сам по себе уже достаточно деятельный поступок". В тексте запятая стояла, но у меня она почему-то вызывает сомнения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы согласилась с запятой. 'В понимании Достоевского' то же, что 'по мнению Д.'

Answer (score 0):

Да, запятая нужна. Это вводное сочетание.